# How to resolve expected declaration error in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to swift and am trying to build an app. I am receiving "Expected Declaration" error on Xcode when I type the following code.

```html
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
```

Please guide me on how to resolve it. Thanks

Comment: Hello, welcome and good luck. This can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

A *declaration* is one of the things listed in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html

If the compiler is saying it's expecting a declaration, it means you have written something that isn't a declaration in some place in the code where only a declaration is allowed.

In your case `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` is a method on SwiftUI View type, so it would only be valid to put that right after a SwiftUI view, not on its own.  It might be because you have brackets in the wrong place.